# Tashlumin with a minyan

Tags: tefilla, tashlumin

If a person accidentally forgets to daven during the day, in most cases he has the opportunity to "make up" that davening by saying shmoneh esrei twice in the next davening. This is called tashlumin.

Lechatchila, a person should daven with a minyan. Is this the case for tashlumin as well (ignoring the fact that presumably the minyan didn't get up and leave immediately after his first shmoneh esrei)? What if he could never have managed to find a minyan for the tefila that he missed, but happened to have one for his "make up"? Is it as if he davened his missed tefila with a minyan, even though he could not possibly have done that?

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, davening with a Minyan is always a good thing. It is a fairly recent innovation that you can get a Minyan at all hours. In earlier times (and in some places even today) you can't really do that (even if there are enough people living there to support it).

On the other hand, Tashlumin has to be [specifically connected](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/8/108/7) to a time of obligatory prayer, and follow it in reasonably short order. This seems to imply that praying with a second minyan would be a contradiction to this idea.

Also, Tashlumin is a special request for mercy outside of an obligation, so it is more comparable to a Tefilas Nedava, in that it is not something congregational.

Based on the above facts, my answer would be no, there is no reason to specifically go looking for a Minyan, and it doesn't count as a group praying together.

Comment: I don't mean praying with a second minyan. I mean finishing your first tefila and starting again while everyone is still there

Comment: Most disagree with that and allow Tashlumin even if not "follow[ed] in reasonably short order". See for example the critique of the Arukh haShulchan of the Alter Rebbe's innovation, and note the silence of the Shulchan Arukh on the matter.

Comment: "Tashlumin is a special request for mercy outside of an obligation, so it is more comparable to a Tefilas Nedava, in that it is not something congregational." Yet a Chazzan who is repeating Shacharit can be Motzi someone who needs to say Tashlumin for Maariv!

Comment: @Daniel Why would it matter who else is there if they aren't praying?

Comment: @DoubleAA, re the first comment, unfortunately the Kuntres Achron that explains it was lost. re the second, [related](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26896/shliach-tzibbur-and-tashlumim-for-missed-tefillah) and the point being the Chazan doesn't have the obligation (as he already davened) when he is being Yotzei others, so I'm not seeing what that is evidence of.

Comment: @Daniel, IIRC, it only counts to Daven with a Minyan when you start within the first three Brachos with the Minyan. So then I would say definitely not.

Comment: @Yishai That he might have had a reason for coming up with a new Halacha is not going to make anyone accept it. | The Chazzan couldn't Motzi someone in a Nedava.

Answer (score 1):

I've done the following (though now I cannot recall who advised me to do so):

Daven the regular Tefillah (silent Shemoneh 'Esreh) with the Minyan, and then do Tashlumin during the repetition.(Point 1)  This follows from the idea that there are two requirements of Tefillah/Tzibbur - one is **Tefillah BETZIBUR** (praying WITH the congregation), which is fulfilled by praying in sync with the congregation, and one is **Tefillath HATZIBUR** (praying OF the congregation), which is usually fulfilled by the Shaliah Tzibur in the repetition, but which can be fulfilled by anyone who prays in sync with him.(Point 2) I have also heard this latter idea in the name of R' JB Soloveitchik, though I've no idea when/where he said it, along with the idea that if you miss **Tefillah BETZIBUR** you should at least attempt to fulfill **Tefillath HATZIBUR** immediately following.(Point 3)

Essentially, the unknown-origin idea (first point above) appears to me to be an extension of the unknown-origin-Rav idea (second/third points above).

It's not clear to me if the first idea actually is preferable or not, and I can see reasons to advise for/against it.

Comment: What if you're saying tashlumin for mincha at maariv where there's no repetition?

Comment: @Daniel you got me. I don't know.

Comment: If I missed shacharis and go to minyan for mincha, can the tefillat hatzibbur in mincha serve as MY tashlumin for my missed tefilla earlier in the day?

Comment: @rosends if I understand you correctly, yes, that's precisely what I'm describing in my answer.