# Someone illegally parked in a disabled parking spot. Is he liable if a disabled person injures himself

Tags: halacha, torts-damages

Sadly, I read in a local paper, about this incident:

Someone illegally parked in a disabled spot at a doctors office. A disabled person arrived for his doctor's appointment, and saw that the only disabled parking spot was taken. The disabled person was using crutches, so it was difficult for him to walk. The disabled spot was right in front of the building.

He had to park further away. As he walked from his parking spot to the building, he fell in the garage and broke his leg.

Chances are that had he parked in the disabled spot, he would not have fallen. I.e., the accident occurred because he had to make that extra walk. Is the person who illegally parked liable for the damage and / or medical costs?

Comment: That sounds like [Grama](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47953/practical-examples-of-a-grama). In that case, there would be no financial penalty, but the obligation will be in Heaven.

Comment: @yishai how is it a gramma the disabled person has the right to use the spot he doesn't own it,it definitely is not mentchlach but a gramma I don't see

Comment: @sam I'm not following the correlation of ownership and gramma in your claim. Can you explain?

Comment: The fact that a car was there already means it is unavailable and halachachily one cannot damage the illiagl parked car but can have it towed. The main issue of grama is that there is no correlation of between him falling and the spot,he could have fell even if he had the spot near the building, the act of parking in a handicap spot is not a damaging action ,it doesn't cause a person to fall,but it definitely is a problem of ben Adam lechaveiro

Comment: @sam Thanks for the explanation. You may want to develop this as an answer by explaining briefly how gramma works and that this is not within that category.

Comment: שולחן ערוך חושן משפט הלכות חובל בחבירו סימן תכ 
המבעית את חבירו, אף על פי שחלה מהפחד, פטור מדיני אדם וחייב בדיני שמים; והוא שלא נגע בו, כגון שצעק לו מאחוריו, או שנראה לו באפילה וכיוצא בו. וכן אם צעק לו באזנו וחרשו, פטור מדיני אדם וחייב בדיני שמים. אחזו ותקע לו באזנו וחרשו, או שנגע בו והדפו בשעה שהבעיתו, או שאחזו בבגדיו, חייב בתשלומין. 
this is a true grama (not to be confused with garmi) since he didnt do a action with his body,the OP question no relation to the action

Comment: @sam Thanks. Unknown to you, you helped me out on a report that I'm compiling and hope to publish, soon, about deafness and loud music, which is addressed at the end of your quote! An extra BIG thanks for the "side" mitzvah!

Comment: @DanF ,I am glad I can contribute, hatzlacha with your report.