# Can the shaliah tsibbur intend the hazarah to be his own tashlumin?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, halacha-theory, tashlumin, tefillah-betzibbur

If someone was unable for some reason to daven *shaharith* and is thereby eligible to pray a make-up prayer (*tashlumin*) at Minhah, but then ends up being asked to be *shaliah ssibbur* when he gets to shul, can that person intend his silent/prayer to be his Minhah and the *hazarah* to count for his *tashlumin*?

Is this possible? Why or why not?

Please cite your sources.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26896/759 (seemingly the "why" question is a dupe)